# Does a factory automatically run a method in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to write a test for a model which is working perfectly - but for some reason the test is not returning the expected result.

My model contains this:

```
after_validation :set_conference

  def rand_conference
    r = rand.to_s[2..8]
    while conference == r
        r = rand.to_s[2..8]
    end
    r
  end

  def set_conference
    self.conference = rand_conference unless conference.presence
  end
end
```

And in my model test I am testing this (ideally I would be testing if 'conference' is a 6 digit number, but for now just a 'not nil' would suffice):

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    name "Test"
    description "Lorem Ipsum"
    category "template"
  end
end
```

Model_spec:

```
  before (:each) do
    @plan = build(:plan)
  end


 it "has a conference number" do
   expect(@plan.conference).not_to be_empty
 end
```

As a result i get:

```
1) Plan has a conference number
     Failure/Error: expect(@plan.conference).not_to be_empty
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

Does factorygirl use the after_validation callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am trying to write a test for a model which is working perfectly - but for some reason the test is not returning the expected result.*

The test is not returning the expected result because the `after_validation` callback is never called which is why `conference` attribute is `nil`. So `@plan.conference` is nil and you cannot call `empty?` on `nil` object. Hence, the error `undefined method 'empty?' for nil:NilClass`

`@plan = build(:plan)` would just create an instance of `Plan` model as per the attributes specified in `factory :plan` and assign it to instance variable `@plan`. **It will definitely not run any validations and obviously no `ActiveRecord` callbacks.**

Just change the before block as

```
before (:each) do
  @plan = create(:plan)  ## create record in database
end
```

With this your `after_validation` callback would be triggered as you actually create a record in database.

For reference:

> Callbacks are methods that get called at certain moments of an
>   object's life cycle. With callbacks it is possible to write code that
>   will run whenever an **Active Record object is created, saved, updated,
>   deleted, validated, or loaded from the database**.

Comment: Problem solved, that did the trick. Plus point for extremely well structured explanation! Further down there is an answer from @fivedigit which works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the callbacks are automatically run. However, you used `FactoryGirl.build` to build a plan, which only initializes the object but doesn't validate it.

You either need to make sure the validations are run:

```
before (:each) do
  @plan = build(:plan)
end

it "has a conference number" do
  @plan.valid?
  expect(@plan.conference).not_to be_empty
end
```

Or you need to call `FactoryGirl.create` to create your plan, but this would also create it in your test database:

```
before (:each) do
  @plan = create(:plan)
end

it "has a conference number" do
  expect(@plan.conference).not_to be_empty
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That works like a charm as well. Do you by any chance know what is the faster approach - using 'create' or 'build'+'valid?' ?

Comment: I try to avoid the `create` as much as possible, as they make the tests slower since they involve I/O. I'd rather trigger a validation when testing a validation callback.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most abvious way is to be explicit like this :

```
it  "has a conference number" do
  @plan = build(:plan)
  @plan.set_conference
  expect(@plan.conference).not_to be_empty
end
```

Anyway, I don't recommend to use callbacks. I think it's preferable to use [service objects](http://stevelorek.com/service-objects.html).

Comment: Thank you! I think the other solutions work better in my case since they do use my validations - but I'll definitely have a look into service objects!